# Google App Script showing a prompt in doc not working with out spreadsheet permission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am trying to show a message box in Google Doc using App Script.

`Browser.msgBox("Hi There");`

When I run this I am getting the below error.

> You do not have permission to call Browser.msgBox. Required
>   permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly
>   || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets) (line 2, file
>   "restore")

The following are the manifest entries present in my doc project.

```
 "oauthScopes" : [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/activity",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp"
  ]
```

Can anyone tell me how to make `Browser.msgBox("Hi There")` work without adding sheet permissions in manifest?

Answer (score 2):

- You want to open a dialog on Google Document.

If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? Unfortunately, Class Browser can be used for Spreadsheet. [The official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser) says as follows.

> This class provides access to dialog boxes specific to Google Sheets.
>
> The methods in this class are only available for use in the context of a Google Spreadsheet. Please use G Suite dialogs instead.

So how about using Class Ui as follows?

```
DocumentApp.getUi().alert("Hi There");
```

- In this case, no scopes are used.

#### References:

- [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)
- [Class Browser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.